# Как правильно в данном случае употребляется наращение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Библиотека, представленная 60-ю тысячами книг.

Comment: Статистика. За последние полгода  10 заданных вопросов и только один принятый ответ. Проблемы с качеством?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Библиотека, представленная **60 тысячами книг**.*

В заданном предложении **форма Т.п.** для числительного определяется по грамматическому существительному **"тысячами"**.

Наращение не используется  для **любых количественных** числительных (только для порядковых).

Пример. ***Более 60 тысяч книг** будут доступны посетителям новой модельной библиотеки.*